# handling data loss from third party integrations

Tags: database, api, stripe-payments

Just curious on best practices for handling potential data loss with a third party integration.
For example, lets say that im integrating stripe for payments. If our platform has a credit system (a user needs X number of credits to do an action on the site), how would you reconcile a loss of data between the platform and after a purchase is made? Going into the example: a user is on the site, purchases a pack of credits for $10. Our platform calls stripe payment when the user clicks "purchase," the purchase is successful but all of a sudden a loss of power happens. We receive the $10 in our stripe, but on our platform the purchase was never "complete" because the loss of power happened immediately after the purchase was made, and there was no time for our system to receive the authorization code to store as completed. I'd imagine this could be common, or in another case where the purchase is complete, but there is some issue between receiving the success code from the payment processor and it causes delay. So, how do you handle this loss of data?
I could think of maybe storing a payment intent on our database with payment status "incomplete" and once a payment is made and we get a code back from stripe, then we update our database with "complete" and we have some job that polls this database every hour or something to check for "incomplete" payments.
What is common in this case?

Comment: How would you distinguish a data loss from a user not completing the transaction?  A data loss due to hardware mishap happens so infrequently, It would probably be better to handle it case by case.

Comment: If the action happened on Stripe you get a webhook, like in your example payment_intent.payment_succeeded. Those events get retried over 3 days so you will eventually get them and can reconcile your system, even if your server was down for a while. https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices#retry-logic